# Adding touchableOpacity to an Image component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

Simple question: How do I add a TouchableOpacity component to an image? This is the way I'm doing it:

```
<View style = { styles.categoryContainer }>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('xScreen')}
                        >
                            <Image 
                                style = {styles.categoriesImages}
                                source = {require('./img/xImage.png')}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

These are the styles that are mapped to the components:

```
categoryContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        margin: 10,
        
    },
    categoriesImages: {
       display: 'flex',
       height: 70,
       width: 70
    },
```

When I run the app on expo, the image simply disappears. Removing the TouchableOpacity component brings the image back.

Maybe someone can provide an explanation as to why this doesn't work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post the styles?

Comment: @DannyBuonocore Uploaded the styles and created a repo over at Github for the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just assuming this is the problem, but without the styles it's a bit hard to really know.

Basically your **Image** must have a width and height in percentage, and you wrapped the image with **TouchableOpacity**, which doesn't have "size". So you have two ways to solve your issue:

- You map a style to **TouchableOpacity** with the width and height of your
  ***styles.categoriesImages*** and the **Image** will simply have 100% on both
  width and height
- Define a width and height for the image that's not a percentage but an actual value, and the **TouchableOpacity** will simply adapt to it's content size

Comment: I've just edited in the styles, also tried assigning width and height to the touchableOpacity component but it still is disappearing.

Comment: Add resize mode to your image, cover or contain should help

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work either. I'm having a really hard time getting what's wrong...

Comment: I created a repo over at github, if you want to check it out it's https://github.com/larguelles/imagesdisappearing